# iOS - Fit NSString into UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to fit the twitter username and tweet into a cell and am doing this by:

```
NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"], [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];


NSString *tweet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet[@"text"]];
```

[image: The entire NSString of the tweet is not fitting into the cell]

I tried the following in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as suggested in another question on here:

```
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"], [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];


NSString *tweetData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet[@"text"]];

CGRect head = [header boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:nil context:nil];

CGRect tweetData2 = [tweetData boundingRectWithSize:CGSize(300.f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:nil context:nil];

CGSize size = head.size;
CGSize size2 = tweetData2.size;

CGFloat n = size.height;
CGFloat m = size2.height;

NSLog(@"%f", n + m);

return (n + m) > 65.0 ? (m + n) : 65.0;
```

I'm just trying to show the whole tweet and resize the cell accordingly instead of having the "..." appear

Comment: This is now the 3rd question you've asked on the same basic issue. Why?

Comment: @rmaddy ive figured it out a little bit but can't get to the end result, hope somebody can lead me in the right direction

Comment: That's doesn't explain why you've posted 3 questions in short order. Please stop. Stick to one question. If you need to clarify you can edit your question. No need to post another a few minutes later.

Comment: Can't believe you posted the same questions 3 times in, like, 3 hours.  I recall seeing a good response the first time you asked the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

## define COMMENT_LABEL_WIDTH 170

## define COMMENT_LABEL_MIN_HEIGHT 60

## define COMMENT_LABEL_PADDING 10

set    selectedIndex = -1; in view did load.

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(COMMENT_LABEL_WIDTH, 200);
    
    CGSize labelHeighSize = [yourstring sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
                                                                              constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                                                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return labelHeighSize.height;
    
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    
            if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
            {
                if([self getLabelHeightForIndex:indexPath.row]>yourminimumcellheight)
                {
                    return [self getLabelHeightForIndex:indexPath.row]+40;
                }
                else
                {
                    return COMMENT_LABEL_MIN_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            else {
                return COMMENT_LABEL_MIN_HEIGHT;
            }
}



  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
        
         UITableViewCell *cell;
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
            {
                CGFloat labelHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:indexPath.row];
                UILabel *comment;
                if(labelHeight >your minimum cell height)
                {
                 comment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,labelHeight)];
                            
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  comment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
                            
                 }
        }
       else
       {
        comment = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
       }
    
   }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
           {
               selectedIndex = -1;
               [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
               
               return;
           }
           
           if(selectedIndex >= 0)
           {
               NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
               selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
               [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           }
           
           selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
           [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: thanx, if u have another query pls ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this by using of the `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` :

```
 NSString *text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"], [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:30], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect framee = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(Maximum_width,Maximum_height)
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                    attributes:attributesDictionary
                                       context:nil];

    CGSize size = framee.size;
    NSLog(@"indexPAth %d %f",indexPath.section, size.height);
    return size.height +40;
```